# WP Homepage disappeared after host migration

Tags: wordpress, migration, hosting

I recently moved a wordpress website from one host to another and my homepage doesn't load. Its a standard homepage that shows my latest posts.

I tried disabling plugins and changing themes, but it still doesn't load up. Other pages on the website load up properly via direct link, but not the homepage.

Has anyone ever faced this? Any help would be appreciated.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

How are you trying to access the homepage?

Please make sure you have set the homepage as your front page under General -> Reading settings page.

[See this image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/c2cGT.png)

Comment: Right now the General>Reading Settings are set to show my latest posts.

Comment: Your homepage is an actual page or you are showing the latest blog posts, if it's not a page where you including the posts then please make sure you have posts available in posts.

Sharing the actual link to the homepage will help.

Comment: Something is not right, the homepage is blank, there is nothing in code, try setting any page for homepage and see if it works.

Comment: I tried setting the homepage in General&gt;Reading Settings to a static page, and I&#39;m still greeted to a blank page.

Could it be that when I migrated the stuff, I missed a file? I used the Duplicator plugin to migrate.

Comment: Check Permalinks under Settings and if that doesnt help then you didnt move the site properly.

Comment: Try viewing the static page on frontend and if the page appears just fine but it doesnt work as a homepage the  most likely duplicator didnt do the job well or you may have missed a step.

Answer (score 0):

Start troubleshooting from the very first thing go to setting and check whether the front static page is set with desired home page or not, secondly go to permalinks set it to default then reset to desired structure, third go to general setting double check the website new URL mention there is exactly same. After checking all these elements problem still existing so I must recommend you to re import the complete website all over again to avoid future hassles. There is nothing big rocket science behind migration you can use [All-in-One WP Migration](https://wordpress.org/plugins/all-in-one-wp-migration/) or follow the [3 steps WordPress migration guide](https://www.cloudways.com/blog/migrate-wordpress-to-another-host/). Sometime its happens when database or the core files are not import properly WordPress usually back fire many errors and exceptions.

Comment: Thanks for your input. I tried everything you said, but the problem persists. I even tried reinstalling WP from the settings menu. Unfortunately, re importing isn't an option anymore as my data has already been deleted from the old host.